# Failed to refresh Access Token when using Google OAuth2.0 credentials

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-analytics-4

I am trying to use GA4 API (with Google Python Client & Google Analytics Data Python Client) of Google with the Credentials authentication:

```
        credentials = Credentials(
            token=config['access_token'],
            refresh_token=config['refresh_token'],
            client_id=config['client_id'],
            client_secret=config['client_secret'],
            token_uri="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
        )
```

This is working when my access token is not expired. However, this access token is expiring after 1 hour and I want to refresh it via following method:

```
credentials.refresh(google.auth.transport.requests.Request())
```

However, this code is returning "invalid_grant" error.

For that problem, I checked almost everything suggested (i.e. system clock/ntp, user permissions, etc.) however I couldn't fix the problem.

Also, I can't figure out about the refresh_token that I use is valid for Google Analytics 4 or not.

So, the questions are:

1. How can I able to solve this problem?
2. How can I assure that the refresh_token is valid for GA4?
3. If not valid, how can I refresh the refresh_token?
4. Is there any suggestion on the refresh of access_token, any other method or anything else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the solution was creating new OAuth client and generate a refresh_token for that account depend on the Google Analytics scope.

For that purpose, after I create the new client, I downloaded the client_secrets.json and run the [Complete Example by Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#example) and finally I am able to refresh the token.